# How to destroy a parent object (company) with has_many users which does not pass validation / callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Company` model which `has_many :users, dependent: :destroy`. The `User` model has a `before_destroy :validate_remaining_admins` callback method which prevents destroying the last admin user of a company.

```
def validate_remaining_admins
  return unless admin?

  remaining_admins = company.users.where.not(id: id).admin
  if company && !company.marked_for_destruction? && remaining_admins.empty?
    errors.add(:base, :validate_remaining_admins)
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

This as all good so far but i'm struggling with destroying the company.
What is the best practice to solve such a thing?

I tried removing `dependent: :destroy` from the association and create a `before_destroy` method which does `delete_all` of the associated users. But then there is the rollback problem if something goes wrong all users are gone. With `after_destroy` there's a foreign key problem.

Passing an attribute before destroy to delete the users also seems hacky.

In the end it should destroy the company with all it's users using `@company.destroy`.

Comment: @dbugger as far as i know marked_for_destruction? does not fire when used by dependent: :destroy on company.destroy.. it has something to do with nested attributes. company.marked_for_destruction? is also false in the validate_remaining_admins method

Comment: @dbugger do you have an example? i tried it already. looks like it doesn’t get passed down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by overriding the destroy methods of the company model:

```
def destroy
  mark_for_destruction
  super
end

def destroy!
  mark_for_destruction
  super
end
```

`autosave: true` does not have to be on the has_many association for users using this method.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord


has_many :users, dependent: :destroy




before_destroy :destroy_users



private



def destroy_users
users.destroy_all

  end

end
```

Could we try, removing the dependent: :destroy option from the association between the Company and User models.

Instead, define a before_destroy callback in the Company model called destroy_users. Inside this method, use the destroy_all method to delete all associated users of the company.

By doing this, when you call @company.destroy, it will trigger the destroy_users method, which will delete all the associated users before the company itself is destroyed.

Regarding the rollback problem you mentioned, the destroy_all method is designed to handle such situations. If an error occurs during the deletion of users, the transaction will be rolled back, and the company won't be destroyed.

Hopefully, this solution provides a safe and clean way to destroy a company with all its associated users using @company.destroy.